# How to send and receive auth ticket with only using AspNet.Identity between sites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have one site - account.mysite.com which only register/login users in my system.
I want to check user's email and passwords in one site and send something to another site, which definitely determines who login.

Can I use FormsAuthentication?

```
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(name, true, 60);
    string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    return "mysite.com?" + FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName + "=" + encrypted;
```

Or do I need to use some features from aspNet.Identity? If yes, how I can do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MVC 5, then you should also use Identity. However, whether you use ASP.NET Membership (forms auth) or Identity has no bearing on any of this.

Simply, in either scheme, an auth cookie will be set. This is what determines a user's "logged in" status. With each request, the user's browser will send the cookie back to the server, and the server will validate it and either consider the user authenticated or not as a result.

So, this all boils down to making sure that auth cookie is shared between your different sites *and* can be read and validate by each of your sites.

On the first part, cookies are restricted by domain. If the cookie is set on `account.mysite.com` then it will *only* be sent to `account.mysite.com`. However, you can set it as a wildcard, so that it will be sent to anything on `*.mysite.com`. That then would allow `account.mysite.com` to set the cookie and still have it be sent to something like `subdomain.mysite.com`. If you have completely different domains in play though, like `account.mysite.com` and you want that to log you in at `foo.com`, that's not possible. The only way to handle that situation is set up a SSO implementation which is non-trivial and far beyond the scope of what can be reasonably answered here. There's entire companies devoted only to setting up SSO for organizations.

So, assuming you're not dealing with different domains and you can at least get each site to get the same cookie, then next part is unencrypting that cookie. The auth cookie is encrypted before it is set, so it can only be read by a site that knows how to decrypt it. The encryption is based on the machine key, so essentially, all your sites need to share the same machine key. For more information, see: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755177(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer.